# Asp.Net Mvc Core project does not compile at first try

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm working on an MVC Core project. My problem is that when I press to compile the project it builds and opens the browser but then the browser is suddenly closed by itself before I see the web app, after that I press again the button to compile the project and it works just fine. After the first build fails the applications successfully runs every time I compile it unless I change anything in the code.
So if I change anything in the `.cstml` or `.cs` and press to run the app it will fail again for the first time..

I don't know what to check or what to do, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds pretty weird. Would you be able to share any debug/log error message when the app first crash? that way I/we can try to understand the problem a little bit better.

Comment: Is this IIS Express or Kestrel?  I've experienced this behavior intermittently with IIS Express but not with Kestrel.

Comment: have you tried: iisreset? restarting windows?